# Slow down player gradually using rigidbody?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer and want the player to slowly  slow down after releasing the left/right buttons.

I haven't found any good solutions on the internet. Here is my code:

```
bool isSprinting =  Input.GetButton("Sprint");
float playerInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if(!isSprinting)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(playerInput * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(playerInput * runSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        

        if(rb.velocity.x > 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        }
        else if(rb.velocity.x < 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually reduce the velocity, use `Rigidbody2D.Drag`, or use Input smoothening.

To manually slow down the Rigidbody2D, you could do something like the following. This should only be done in a FixedUpdate to keep consistent behavior even with varying frame rates.

```
const float SMALL_INPUT_CONSTANT = 0.01f;//increase to slow down even if a controller's joystick is slightly pressed
const float LERP_CONST_BETWEEN_0_AND_1 = 0.05f;//increase to slow down faster
if(Mathf.Abs(playerInput) < SMALL_INPUT_CONSTANT){
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, 0, LERP_CONST_BETWEEN_0_AND_1), rb.velocity.y);
}
else
{
//insert other movement code here (the if(!isSprinting)...else... code you posted), because you shouldn't set the velocity if the user isn't giving `Horizontal` input
}
```

You can increase Rigidbody2D.Drag in the Editor, it's labeled as `Linear Drag`. This will make the Rigidbody2D fall like a feather, so only use it if that's what you want.

[image: Linear Drag on Rigidbody2D in Editor]

I haven't used Input smoothening, but I think it would be the `Gravity` variable in the Input Manager.

[image: Input Manager]